# The method runOnUiThread(Runnable) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Tags: android, dialog, thread-safety, runnable, ui-thread

I am trying to create a dialog from a non-UI thread, in onUtteranceCompleted():

```
runOnUiThread(
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() { MyDialog.Prompt(this); }
    }).start());
```

Prompt() is a simple **static** method of the class MyDialog:

```
  static public void Prompt(Activity activity) {
    MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog();
    myDialog.showAlert("Alert", activity);     
  }
```

The problem is that I cam getting two errors for what I am trying to do:

1. The method runOnUiThread(Runnable)
   in the type Activity is not
   applicable for the arguments (void)
2. The method Prompt(Activity) in the
   type MyDialog is not applicable
   for the arguments (new Runnable(){})

All I wanted is "do it right" by deferring dialog creation to a UI thread, but it appears that I am missing something fundamental.

What am I missing and how do I accomplish the seemingly simple task that I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It must be:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() { MyDialog.Prompt(NameOfYourActivity.this); }
    });
```

It says that *is not applicable for the arguments (void)* because you are trying to run a thread using the start method (which is a void method). `runOnUiThread` receives a runnable object, and you don't have to worry about starting it, that's done by the OS for you.

With regards to the second error, it happens because in that scope `this` is referring to the `Runnable` object that you are initializing, rather than the reference to the activity. So, you have to explicitly tell what `this` you are referring to (in this case `YourActivityName.this`).

Comment: It seems that you can only use runOnUiThread from an Activity, nothing else.

Comment: Yes, that's right... that's the only place where it makes sense to use it.

Comment: I saved my 'this' in a final context variable:  final Context ctx; then used that in the call to my method: public void run(){ try { myList =MyStaticClass.getInstance(ctx);}catch{(Exception e){}